# jQuery - $(window).load vs $(window).prop('complete')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm programming with jQuery after Modernizr calling. 
Modernizr use AJAX to load JavaScript and CSS code.

**Called code doesn't work with**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Some code
});
```

Same with other selectors like $('img'), $('object'), etc...

**But works with:**

```
$(window).prop('complete',function(){
   // Some code
});
```

And other selectors...

Testing both codes without Modernizr, $(window).prop('complete') **fire first**

What's the difference beetween them?

Why everybody use $(window).load instead of $(window).prop('complete')?

Comment: `window.complete` is usually a hack for older IE that don't always fire the `onload` event when the content is cached. Also, the current window only loads once, if you're loading content with ajax, it won't fire again. And the most important part, your `prop()` function is just a callback to set the value, it has nothing to do with anything that's even remotely related to the window loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions do entirely different things.

`load` fires a callback function when the page has finished loading. That means it is **asynchronous**; i.e. the code on a subsequent line will likely happen before the callback is run.

`prop` does something entirely different. It is a way of setting a property on an element in a dynamic way. Usually it's used on sets of elements. For example, this would invert all the `checked` properties on all `radio` buttons:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', function(i, oldProp) {
    return !oldProp;
});
```

This code is **synchronous**. That means it is all run immediately; subsequent lines of code are not run until all the callbacks have taken place.

So `$(window).prop('complete', function() {...});` is very odd syntax. It is basically the same as this:

```
window.complete = '...';
```

It does not even remotely do the same thing as `$(window).load()`. It works for setting properties on the `window` object, but there's no conceivable time when that would be useful, in my experience.